In Python, how can I overcome the limitations of scipy.integrate.quad() to integrate the square of the Airy function between 0 and +infinity?
I'm trying to integrate the Airy function (of the first kind, that I'll call Ai from now) squared, between 0 and infinity.
While scipy.special.itairy() works flawlessly for integrating Ai between 0 and infinity, I haven't found a routine for Ai². I'm thus trying to calculate the integral using scipy.integrate.quad().
However, for large values of the upper bound, the value of the integral starts suddenly decreasing (from ~66.99e-3 to values close to zero), and keeps decreasing as the upper bound increases, which is of course impossible for a positive function.
I assume this is due to quad() reaching its absolute error tolerance (set by the parameter espabs, default value 1.49e-8) and simply "crashing" as a result. This is evidenced by the upper subplot on this figure.
Unlike epsabs, changing epsrel or limit doesn't seem to move the threshold after which the integral starts decreasing.
On all 3 subplots, the green curves are obtained with the default value of epsabs. The bottom left subplot shows that the integral value decreases exponentially with the upper bound once the threshold is crossed, and the bottom right subplot shows that the threshold is crossed when the upper bound reaches x ~ 5226, using the default value of espabs.
How can I overcome this problem?
The remaining part of the integral (between the threshold and +infinity) is, most likely, very close to zero and could potentially be discarded, but this feels like a jerry-rigged solution that could cause problems or result in very case-specific code, as I need to calculate the integral of Ai²(ax + b) further down the line, for different values of (a, b).

Here is the code to generate the figure :
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.special import airy

fig = plt.figure()

ax2 = plt.subplot(223)
ax3 = plt.subplot(224)
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)

# subplot 1
xmax1 = np.linspace(1000, 10000, 100)
for error,clr in zip([10e-5, 10e-7, 1.49e-8, 10e-11, 10e-13, 10e-16],
                     ['red','darkorange','forestgreen','cornflowerblue','blue']
                     ):
    airy_square_int1 = [integrate.quad(lambda x: (airy(x)[0])**2, 
                                       0, 
                                       end, 
                                       epsabs = error,
                                       # epsrel = 10**(-15),
                                       limit = 20
                                       )[0] 
                        for end in xmax1
                        ]

    ax1.plot(xmax1, 
             airy_square_int1, 
             label ='epsabs = {}'.format(error),
             color = clr
             )

ax1.set_xlabel("x")
ax1.set_ylabel("integral of Ai² from 0 to x")
plt.legend()

# subplot 2
xmax2 = np.linspace(6000, 20000, 100)
airy_square_int2 = [integrate.quad(lambda x: (airy(x)[0])**2,
                                   0, 
                                   end
                                   )[0] 
                    for end in xmax2
                    ]

ax2.plot(xmax2, airy_square_int2, color = 'forestgreen')
ax2.set_xlabel("x")
ax2.set_ylabel("integral of Ai² from 0 to x")

# subplot 3
xmax3 = np.linspace(5226, 5227, 100)
airy_square_int3 = [integrate.quad(lambda x: (airy(x)[0])**2, 
                                   0, 
                                   end
                                   )[0] 
                    for end in xmax3
                    ]

ax3.plot(xmax3 - 5226, airy_square_int3, '+', color = 'forestgreen')
ax3.set_xlabel("x - 5226")

plt.tight_layout(pad = 0.5)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.5)
plt.savefig("integral_AiSquared_behavior.png")
            


Is the goal here only to get the value or to show the integral result with a variable upper limit?

The goal is to get the value of the integral between 0 and +infinity. I simply started playing with the variable upper limit to understand what was happening, and if the errors I was getting were simply a convergence problem, when I noticed that threshold.

I might have to go back to the drawing board because, when typing this reply, I ran integrate.quad(lambda x: (airy(x)[0])**2, 0, np.inf) and it ran ok, giving ~66.99e-3 as a result.
I started writing the code in my question specifically to post it here; my original code, which prompted me to investigate further, was trying to integrate Ai²(ax + b)  between 0 and np.inf, and I kept getting "IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved. [...]"
The weird threshold behavior still happens around 5226 with the default value of espabs though.

That's what I was going to point out. As per the documentation, the code will use a different integration method when you provide np.inf as one of the limits. The code doesn't seem to use an ideal method when you provide a large but not infinite integration limit.

That would make sense! I read that it uses qagse for infinite intervals, but I didn't put two and two together. I still have to figure out why it returns nan and the error mentioned above when I try to integrate Ai²(ax + b) instead of simply Ai²(x), but that is outside the scope of this question.
You can post your comment as an answer if you wish to, and I'll accept it.

If the goal is simply to get the value of the integral, then, as per the documentation, you should use np.inf for the upper integration limit. The underlying code will use different techniques depending on the domain of the integral, and using very large numbers doesn't "activate" the techniques used for semi-infinite or infinite domains.
Here is a short example code to get the integral value:
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import airy
from scipy.integrate import quad

res = quad(lambda x: airy(x)[0]**2, 0, np.inf)
print(res)  # (0.066987483779594, 1.4764521990609899e-08)

This result matches WolframAlpha's result of 0.0669875.

As a follow-up to what we were discussing in the comments, I should add that my issue was arising from trying to integrate x -> (Ai(ax + b))² between 0 and +inf, with a ~ 10^6 and b ~ -1, leading to a function that was close to 0 after only ~ 2e-5.
Integrating y -> (Ai(y + b))^2 instead (from 0 to +np.inf without having to resort to any tricks like splitting intervals) then dividing the result by a worked perfectly.
